# How to count working days in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, arrays, list, function

What I want to do is calculate working days from two defined dates (beginning of month and end of the month).

I am working with a function that I found out which receives three parameters, `start date`, `end date`, and `a list of dates of non-working days` (holidays and others).

The code below gives me 23 working days but the actual result must be `22 working days`.

For example

```
Start date is - 2020-03-01 and
End Date is - 2020-03-31 
With 7 non-working days
```

(Dates are selected from DatePickerDialog and are stored in variables `dateIni` and `dateFin`)

```
public class FragmentConsultas extends Fragment 
{
    EditText fechaIni, fechaFin;
    Button btAsistencia;
    private int anioIni, mesIni, diaIni, anioFin, mesFin, diaFin;
    private String  sDiaI, sMesI, sDiaF, sMesF;
    List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
    private Calendar mcurrentDateFin, mcurrentDateIni;
    private Calendar dateIni, dateFin;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_consultas, container, false);

        fechaIni = v.findViewById(R.id.fechaIni);
        fechaFin = v.findViewById(R.id.fechaFin);
        btAsistencia = v.findViewById(R.id.btAsistencia);

        dates.add(new Date(2020-1-1));
        dates.add(new Date(2020-2-24));
        dates.add(new Date(2020-2-25));
        dates.add(new Date(2020-3-23));
        dates.add(new Date(2020-3-24));
        dates.add(new Date(2020-4-2));
        dates.add(new Date(2020-4-9));

        fechaIni.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mcurrentDateIni = Calendar.getInstance();
                anioIni = mcurrentDateIni.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                mesIni = mcurrentDateIni.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                diaIni = mcurrentDateIni.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog mDatePicker;
                mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), R.style.DialogTheme, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {

                        if (selectedday < 9){
                            sDiaI = "0" + String.valueOf(selectedday);
                        }else{
                            sDiaI =  String.valueOf(selectedday);
                        }

                        if (selectedmonth < 9){
                            sMesI = "0" + String.valueOf(selectedmonth+1);
                        }else if (selectedmonth == 9) {
                            sMesI = String.valueOf(selectedmonth+1);
                        }else{
                            sMesI = String.valueOf(selectedmonth+1);
                        }

                        fechaIni.setText(selectedyear + "-" + sMesI + "-" + sDiaI);
                        dateIni = new GregorianCalendar(selectedyear, selectedmonth, selectedday);

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Fecha de inicio: " + dateIni, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }, anioIni, mesIni, diaIni);
                mDatePicker.show();
            }
        });

        fechaFin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mcurrentDateFin = Calendar.getInstance();
                anioFin = mcurrentDateFin.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                mesFin = mcurrentDateFin.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                diaFin = mcurrentDateFin.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog mDatePicker;
                mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), R.style.DialogTheme, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {

                        if (selectedday < 9){
                            sDiaF = "0" + String.valueOf(selectedday);
                        }else{
                            sDiaF =  String.valueOf(selectedday);
                        }

                        if (selectedmonth < 9){
                            sMesF = "0" + String.valueOf(selectedmonth+1);
                        }else if (selectedmonth == 9) {
                            sMesF = String.valueOf(selectedmonth+1);
                        }else{
                            sMesF = String.valueOf(selectedmonth+1);
                        }

                        fechaFin.setText(selectedyear + "-" + sMesF + "-" + sDiaF);
                        dateFin = new GregorianCalendar(selectedyear, selectedmonth, selectedyear);

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Fecha fin: " + dateFin, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }, anioFin, mesFin, diaFin);
                mDatePicker.show();
            }
        });


        btAsistencia.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int diasLab = diasHabiles(dateIni, dateFin, dates);

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Días Laborables: " + diasLab, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        return v;

    }

    public int diasHabiles(Calendar fechaInicial, Calendar fechaFinal, List<Date> listaFechasNoLaborables) {
        int diffDays = 0;
        boolean diaHabil = false;
        //mientras la fecha inicial sea menor o igual que la fecha final se cuentan los dias
        while (fechaInicial.before(fechaFinal) || fechaInicial.equals(fechaFinal)) {

            if (!listaFechasNoLaborables.isEmpty()) {
                for (Date date : listaFechasNoLaborables) {
                    Date fechaNoLaborablecalendar = fechaInicial.getTime();
                    //si el dia de la semana de la fecha minima es diferente de sabado o domingo
                    if (fechaInicial.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY && fechaInicial.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY && !fechaNoLaborablecalendar.equals(date)) {
                        //se aumentan los dias de diferencia entre min y max
                        diaHabil = true;
                    } else {
                        diaHabil = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (fechaInicial.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY && fechaInicial.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY) {
                    //se aumentan los dias de diferencia entre min y max
                    diffDays++;
                }
            }
            if (diaHabil == true) {
                diffDays++;
            }
            //se suma 1 dia para hacer la validacion del siguiente dia.
            fechaInicial.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
        return diffDays;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow! Please write in English so that we can understand the problem that you are having. Thank you!

Comment: You need to write your question in english or use [es.stackoverflow.com](http://es.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: What I want to do is calculate from two dates (beginning of month and end of month) the number of working days, I am working with a function that I found out there that receives three parameters, start date, end date, and one list of dates of non-working days (holidays and others). With the code as it is, it gives me 23 working days and the truth is that March has 22 without counting those on the list (holidays and that)

For example:

2020-03-01 and 2020-03-31 (As you can see in the code these dates are selected from a DatePickerDialog and stored in the variables dateIni and dateFin)

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Do you get errors? If so, what are they? If not, how does the result differ from what you want?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't how you initialize a `Date` object:

```java
new Date(2020-3-24)
```

`2020-3-24` is subtraction, so you're initializing it to 2020-3-24=1993 [milliseconds since the start of January 1 1970 in GMT](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date#Date(long)).

You probably meant to use the [constructor that takes a year, month, and day](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date#Date(int,%20int,%20int)):

```java
new Date(2020, 3, 24)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've already solved it. I have modified the function, now the parameters it receives are the three of Calendar type. The previous code counted the working days but the compare dates part with the arraylist (which contains holidays) did not work.
I share the solution in case anyone uses it.

public class FragmentConsultas extends Fragment {

```
EditText fechaIni, fechaFin;
Button btAsistencia;
private int anioIni, mesIni, diaIni, anioFin, mesFin, diaFin;
private String  sDiaI, sMesI, sDiaF, sMesF;
List<Calendar> dates = new ArrayList<Calendar>();
private Calendar mcurrentDateFin, mcurrentDateIni;
private Calendar dateIni, dateFin, cal, cal1, cal2, cal3;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_consultas, container, false);

    fechaIni = v.findViewById(R.id.fechaIni);
    fechaFin = v.findViewById(R.id.fechaFin);
    btAsistencia = v.findViewById(R.id.btAsistencia);

    cal = new GregorianCalendar(2020, Calendar.MARCH, 23);
    cal1 = new GregorianCalendar(2020,Calendar.MARCH,24);
    cal2 = new GregorianCalendar(2020, Calendar.MARCH,3);
    cal3 = new GregorianCalendar(2020,Calendar.MARCH,9);

    dates.add(cal);
    dates.add(cal1);
    dates.add(cal2);
    dates.add(cal3);


    fechaIni.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mcurrentDateIni = Calendar.getInstance();
            anioIni = mcurrentDateIni.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mesIni = mcurrentDateIni.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            diaIni = mcurrentDateIni.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog mDatePicker;
            mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), R.style.DialogTheme, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {

                    if (selectedday < 9){
                        sDiaI = "0" + String.valueOf(selectedday);
                    }else{
                        sDiaI =  String.valueOf(selectedday);
                    }

                    if (selectedmonth < 9){
                        sMesI = "0" + String.valueOf(selectedmonth+1);
                    }else if (selectedmonth == 9) {
                        sMesI = String.valueOf(selectedmonth+1);
                    }else{
                        sMesI = String.valueOf(selectedmonth+1);
                    }

                    fechaIni.setText(selectedyear + "-" + sMesI + "-" + sDiaI);
                    dateIni = new GregorianCalendar(selectedyear, selectedmonth, selectedday);

                }
            }, anioIni, mesIni, diaIni);
            mDatePicker.show();
        }
    });

    fechaFin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mcurrentDateFin = Calendar.getInstance();
            anioFin = mcurrentDateFin.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mesFin = mcurrentDateFin.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            diaFin = mcurrentDateFin.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog mDatePicker;
            mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), R.style.DialogTheme, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {

                    if (selectedday < 9){
                        sDiaF = "0" + String.valueOf(selectedday);
                    }else{
                        sDiaF =  String.valueOf(selectedday);
                    }

                    if (selectedmonth < 9){
                        sMesF = "0" + String.valueOf(selectedmonth+1);
                    }else if (selectedmonth == 9) {
                        sMesF = String.valueOf(selectedmonth+1);
                    }else{
                        sMesF = String.valueOf(selectedmonth+1);
                    }

                    fechaFin.setText(selectedyear + "-" + sMesF + "-" + sDiaF);
                    dateFin = new GregorianCalendar(selectedyear, selectedmonth, selectedday);

                }
            }, anioFin, mesFin, diaFin);
            mDatePicker.show();
        }
    });


    btAsistencia.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int diasLab = diasHabiles(dateIni, dateFin, dates);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Días Laborables: " + diasLab, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    return v;

}

public int diasHabiles(Calendar fechaInicial, Calendar fechaFinal, List<Calendar> listaFechasNoLaborables) {
    int diffDays = 0;
    boolean diaHabil = false;
    //mientras la fecha inicial sea menor o igual que la fecha final se cuentan los dias
    while (fechaInicial.before(fechaFinal) || fechaInicial.equals(fechaFinal)) {

        if (!listaFechasNoLaborables.isEmpty()) {
            for (Calendar date : listaFechasNoLaborables) {
                Date fechaNoLaborablecalendar = fechaInicial.getTime();

                Log.e("FECHANOLABORABLE", String.valueOf(fechaNoLaborablecalendar));
                Log.e("FECHADATE", String.valueOf(date.getTime()));

                //si el dia de la semana de la fecha minima es diferente de sabado o domingo
                if ((fechaInicial.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY) && (fechaInicial.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY) && (!fechaNoLaborablecalendar.equals(date.getTime()))) {
                    //se aumentan los dias de diferencia entre min y max
                    diaHabil = true;
                } else {
                    diaHabil = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (fechaInicial.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY && fechaInicial.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY) {
                //se aumentan los dias de diferencia entre min y max
                diffDays++;
            }
        }
        if (diaHabil) {
            diffDays++;
        }
        //se suma 1 dia para hacer la validacion del siguiente dia.
        fechaInicial.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    return diffDays;
}
```

}